# How to pass the selected tags from checkbox to a modal in real time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tags, native

I need to select tags in TagScreen, then go back to CRMtags and see those selected tags. What is currently happening is that I see selected tags for example tag1 and tag2 in CRMtags and then I select more tags, for example tag3 and tag4 in TagScreen and go back to CRMtags I can see only the tag1 and tag2, then I go to TagScreen again and select tag5 then go back to CRMtags and now tag3 and tag4 are selected so now I have tag1, tag2, tag3 and tag4 selected in CRMtags. If I go again to TagScreen and select tag5 then go back to CRMtags I'll only get tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 selected, I'll need to go back to TagScreen and select tag5 again so I can see it on CRMtags.

TagScreen

```
const TagScreen = (props) => {
    // Extract necessary props and state variables
    const {
        navigation = {},
        route: {
            params: { tags = [], allTags = [], roomInfo = {} },
        },
    } = props;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {
        bot: { id: botId },
        id: roomId,
    } = roomInfo;
    const [tagsChecked, setTagsChecked] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const newTags = allTags.map((tag) => {
            const isChecked = tags.some((_tag) => _tag.id === tag.id);
            return { ...tag, isChecked };
        });
       setTagsChecked(newTags);
}, [tags, allTags]);

    const headerTags = () => (
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <Pressable style={styles.back} onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                <GoBackIcon />
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Tags</Text>
        </View>
    );

    const setCheckboxState = (id, isChecked) => {
        const newTags = tagsChecked.map((tag) => {
            if (tag.id === id) {
                return { ...tag, isChecked };
            }
            return tag;
        });
        setTagsChecked(newTags);
        sendTags(newTags);
    };

    const sendTags = async (newTags) => {
        const tagsChecked = newTags.filter((tag) => tag.isChecked);
        const chatTagsIds = tagsChecked.map((tag) => tag.id);

        const { data } = await postRoomTags({ botId, tags: chatTagsIds, roomId });
        dispatch(setTags(data.tags));
    };

    
    const selectedTagsNames = tagsChecked.filter((tag) => tag.isChecked) .map((tag) => tag.name.es);
    console.log("Selected tags: ", selectedTagsNames);

    const renderTags = ({ item }) => (
        <BouncyCheckbox
            style={{ padding: 10 }}
            iconStyle={{ marginLeft: 15 }}
            text={item.name.es}
            fillColor={item.color}
            isChecked={item.isChecked}
            disableBuiltInState
            textStyle={{
                textDecorationLine: "none",
            }}
            onPress={() => setCheckboxState(item.id, !item.isChecked)}
        />
    );

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white, paddingBottom: 20 }}>
            <FlatList
                data={tagsChecked}
                renderItem={renderTags}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                style={{ paddingHorizontal: 8 }}
                ListHeaderComponent={headerTags}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default TagScreen;
```

CRMTags

```
const CrmTags = (props) => {
    const { isArchived, roomInfo, navigation } = props;
    const tags = useSelector((state) => state.tags); 

    const [showAllTags, setShowAllTags] = useState(false);
    const [allTags, setAllTags] = useState([]);
    const tagsQuantity = tags?.length;
    const userSession = useSelector((state) => state.userSession);
    const { companyId, teams = [] } = userSession;
    const {
        bot: { id: botId },
    } = roomInfo;

    const getAllTags = async () => {
        const { data } = await getTags({ companyId, botId, teams });
        setAllTags(data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllTags();
    }, [companyId, tags]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Etiquetas ({tagsQuantity})</Text>
            <View style={styles.tagsContainer}>
                <View numberOfLines={2} style={[styles.tagsGrid, { height: showAllTags ? "auto" : 29 }]}>
                    {tags.map((tag) => (
                        <Pressable key={tag?.id} style={[styles.tag, { backgroundColor: tag?.color }]}>
                            <Text style={styles.tagText}>{tag?.name?.es}</Text>
                            {!isArchived && <Octicons name="x-circle" size={15} color={colors.primary.dark} />}
                        </Pressable>
                    ))}
                </View>
                {!isArchived && (
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        underlayColor={colors.primary[300]}
                        style={styles.newTag}
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TagScreen", { tags, allTags, roomInfo })}>
                        <AddIcon style={{ color: colors.primary[500], width: 18, height: 18 }} />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                )}
            </View>
            {tagsQuantity > 0 && (
                <Pressable onPress={() => setShowAllTags(!showAllTags)}>
                    <Text style={styles.renderAll}>{!showAllTags ? "Ver todo +" : "Ver menos -"}</Text>
                </Pressable>
            )}
        </View>
    );
};
```

```
export async function postRoomTags({ botId = "", tags = [], roomId = "" }) {
    try {
        const { data } = await JelouApiV1.post(`/bots/${botId}/rooms/tags`, { tags, roomId });
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I need to see in CRMTags exactly the selected tags from TagScreen, like the ones I just selected, avoiding selecting them twice to be able to see them.

This is not my code but it is my task to make it work right. I don't fully understand redux or context yet so I'd like to know if there's a simple way to do this like with props or similar. Or is it really necessary to use Redux.